# Css/jQuery animation for expanding divs to 100% of screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am trying to create an animation for some html elements that are laid out in a quadrant format.  On click of each div, I want them to expand to 100% of the height and width of the container and on click again collapse back to their initial size.  This is a similar animation to that of browsers maximizing and collapsing back to their original size.

What I currently have is working fine, I would just rather have the animation not push the other elements off the screen and also for it not to jump when the header disappears.

How can I do this?  Feel free to use jQuery animation or css3 animations.  Thanks!

Here is a demo of what I currently have: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/48vh9/)
**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.box1').on('click', function() {

        $(this).animate({height: "100%", width: "100%"}, 500);

    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="box-container clearfix">
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>
        <div class="box3"></div>
        <div class="box4"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page-wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 480px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
}

.box-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    background: black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.box1{
    background: yellow;
    height: 190px;
    width: 170px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
} 

.box2 {
    background: red;
    height: 190px;
    width: 180px;
        margin: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.box3 {
    background: green;
    height: 190px;
    width: 170px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
} 

.box4 {
    background: blue;
    height: 190px;
    width: 180px;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This is nice! The only thing is the green box seems to jump out of the frame, and also I would like if the header disappeared or was overlapped..

Comment: Give me a few moments to work on it. :)

Comment: Ok, how is this? I hope it works well but animations may be different across browsers. I'm using chrome and it works pretty good. The only problem which I have with it is that the divs don't grow from their original point but that'll require a lot of coding to fix. The jumping divs shouldn't be as noticeable though. http://jsfiddle.net/48vh9/22/

Comment: Another update.... http://jsfiddle.net/48vh9/24/ That's me for tonight though, if this is good please accept my answer? I'm sure from here the code will be easy for you to fix up.

Answer (score 2):

I have this so far, it's a bit messy and there is no animation yet but bare with my and i'll post an edit with the animation shortly.

http://jsfiddle.net/48vh9/24/

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var full = 0;
    var thisBox;
    var d = {};
    var speed = 900;
    $('.box').on('click', function() {
        thisBox = $(this);
        console.log($(thisBox)[0]);
        if(full === 0){
            $('.box').each(function(){
                if($(this)[0] != $(thisBox)[0]){
                    $(this).fadeOut(1);                     
                }                  
            });
            d.width = "100%";
            d.height = "100%";
            $(this).animate(d,speed,function(){
                $(this).css("top","0px");
                $(this).css("left","0px");
                $(this).css("margin-left","0px");
                $(this).css("margin-top","0px");
                $(this).css("position","absolute");
                }); 
            full = 1;
        }
        else{

            d.width = "170px";
            d.height = "190px";
            $(this).css("position","");
            $(this).css("margin-left","10px");
            $(this).css("margin-top","10px");
            $(this).animate(d,speed,function(){ 
                                       $('.box').each(function(){
                if($(this)[0] != $(thisBox)[0]){
                    $(this).fadeIn("fast");                     
                }                  
            });  });


            full = 0;
        }

    });

});
```

I also changed the html to make each box have the `.box` class.

Comment: Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bonatoc/LymTY/1/ — but maybe you need the boxes on the right to properly animate? For instance, the red one grows under the yellow one due to "float:right;".

Comment: Yeah ideally the other boxes wouldn't moved or be pushed out of the way.  I would either like the expanding div to expand over the other elements or for the other elements to hide before expanding.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine the way it is , if it is not working as expected I would check the deminsions of

```
 <div class="box-container clearfix">
```

when you set something to `100%` that is `100%` of it's parent.  So see that this parent div is in fact taking up the whole screen

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I wasn't clear enough.  I added an Edit section to my question, but I was looking for help in making the animation more smooth and professional such as not having the yellow box jump when the header hides and having the yellow box move over the other elements so it doesn't push them off screen.

Comment: @Chrisgozd - you need to have it positioned absolute , that way it will not affect the other elements on the screen .  The other solution may work , but your one line of code IMO is wayy better , just change css around to make the div that is going to be expanded positioned absolute

Comment: If I change it to absolute position, wont the other elements move around because they are all floated next to eachother?

Comment: uh huh - I mean you to figure out the best design for your scenerio .  You got an answer to your specific problem.  Now you can position them all absolutely, or on click change them to absolute and expand , then make small and go back to float. it's up to you .  ut the solution to your original problem of the bad animation is the absolute position.  My suggestion is to make them all absolute the whole time, I always avoid float.

Comment: The only reason I used float was so that I could dynamically change the number of boxes and they would like up next to eachother.  I could have 4, 3, or 2 boxes with 50% or 100% width and I don't know how I would do that dynamically using position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You can check when width & height is different from `100%` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.box1').on('click', function() {
        if($(this).attr("style") != "height: 100%; width: 100%;")
            $(this).animate({height: "100%", width: "100%"}, 500);
         else 
            $(this).animate({height: "190px", width: "170px"}, 500);
    });

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48vh9/3/)

Another sollution using jquery-ui:

Add this class in your css

**css**

```
.fullsize{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**js**

```
$('.box1').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("fullsize", 1000)
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48vh9/17/)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can make it smoother so that the elements don't jump back into place when the yellow box gets smaller?

Comment: Hmm i suggest another sollution. Check it please.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the window's viewport, I have a function juste for that

```
// Return visible bounds of window
function viewport()
{
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window)) {
       a = 'client';
       e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return {w: e[ a + 'Width' ], h: e[ a + 'Height' ]};
}
```

You can rename "w" and "h" into "width" and "height" and you should get just what you want.

Look here http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/ if you want more info, or just google "viewport javascript" ;)

-- Edit :
Just "store" the original size in order to set it back.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, I can animate the element to be 100% of its container, I just want to make the animation smoother so that the elements don't jump around.

Comment: So use the "transition-duration" css property, set it to a number of seconds and it will be perfect :)
More info : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-duration.asp

Comment: Not sure how that property helps, Would you be able to edit my jsfiddle and show me?